# Fast Multipole Methods

Tags: physics, simulation

My goal is to model electrostatic containment of point charges (protons). I understand the basic N-body potential calculation is O[N^2}, and a potential of q/|ri-rj| (constant mass and charge, classical, non-relativistic, non-magnetic). Recent published Fast Multipole Methods approximate the far-field to far-field force for "well separated" adaptive quad/oct tree cubes or spheres with O[N] calcs [Google Scholar]. What does Mathematica 12 offer for FMM for large N?

Obviously the first step is to partition the geometric space into smaller groups (spatial data structures) of (tree nodes, clusters or buckets) containing max 100 points, that are well-separated r=(radius of enclosing octant or sphere), R= distance between centroids of nodes, R=delta*(ri + rj). Use the exact potential for points within nodes and approximate potential for node centroids. Published papers claim O[N] (actually 5*O[N] due to splits and merges up and down the (implicit) tree plus node-node calcs.) Particles with constant mass and charge per particle, symmetric containment fields (spherical/cylindrical, optional central wire).

Obviously I can calc (analytically) the field inside the container, and apply it to the centroids, and develop a (symplectic?) Hamiltonian to solve eqns of motion (with SPRK?) but the particles move and the clusters change. So a fast potential calc is required.

Comment: To my knowledge, _Mathematica_ itself offers little to nothing in this respect. There is  are some space partition tree structures, but they are IMHO not of great help in this respect.  I say this without grief, btw. This application is a bit too specific for a general-purpose tool like _Mathematica_. I wrote my own FMM-like tool for purposes of numerical optimization of repulsive energies for curves and surfaces. It can also be used to simulate Coulomb forces for point clouds.

Comment: The tool is called "Repulsor" and is presented in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287178/38178). It is not really FMM, but rather a Barnes-Hut method in the sense that it does not use higher order moments and thus it not _that_ accurate. But far field interactions are computed with $O(N)$-complexity directly between cluster like in the FMM method (in contrast, BH lets particles interact with clusters so that the far field computations have complexity $O(N \log(N))$).

Comment: Btw., I don't think that high-order integrators like Runge-Kutta would work well with this class of approximations. They assume a regularity of the right-hand sides of the ODE that is just not there with tree-approximation. I would probably try the Störmer -Verlet method (a.k.a. leapfrog method) first because it is fast and simple (and thus less error-prone) to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your research and references. I am amazed that you can get so deep behind Mathematica's rather buggy front end routines. FYI The recommended solution I found was a symplectic Hamiltonian solver, which I thought NDsolve provided but apparently it is buggy.  Also the Barnes Hut and Stormer-Verlet were unstable for long-term simulation (I had done a FDTD emulation some years before).  Excellent response saved me another 6 months of  trial and error.

Comment: I was hoping to use Mathematica's built-in tools to concentrate on the problem's symbolic simulation then try numerical optimizations.  The multi-grid references will be particularly useful for the discretization of the containers. My formulation actually partitions the the charge-cloud into a "well-separated adaptive sphere-tree." Email me at jimhargi@comcast.net and we can continue this offline.

Comment: Lastly, I'd like to request a copy of your paper on Repulsive Surfaces before I download Repulsor, to see if there is an analogue to the electrostatic confinement of the plasma surface. In the case of a 2d disk or short cylinder, the positive charge cloud  deforms down to a torus of (mostly parallel) circular orbits whose density depends on inversely on the ratio of the container (disc) voltage and the N of protons (and of course the neutralizing electron smear). Limited analysis of 3d orbits might allow the possibility of intersecting orbits. Am looking for efficient numerical simulations..

Comment: Hi Jim, glad to be of help. You can obtain a free copy of the paper along with plenty of other material (talks! movies!) from [Keenan Crane's homepage](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/RepulsiveSurfaces/index.html). Note however that we implemented the paper with a precursor of Repulsor. In particular, there will be no mention of Coulomb potential other than that it does not prevent surface collisions.

Comment: What I forgot to mention: Repulsor is designed for shared memory architectures and only utilizes the CPU. If you want to go really large, then you might want to look out for GPU implementations or MPI-based implementations for distributed memory architectures.